# New instance of chart object affecting existing instance

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following [Mike Bostock's pattern for reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) - closures with getter/setters. But somehow, when I instantiate a new chart object with new properties, existing charts are being updated with these properties:

```
var chart1 = new StackedAreaChart();
d3.select('#chart1')
    .data([data])
    .call(chart1);     

// a new chart - whose properties end up in chart1!
var chart2 = new StackedAreaChart().colors(['green', 'blue']);
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/YZ6Ea/3/. Resize the window to see the first chart re-rendered, with a stylish but unexpected green tint.

I am baffled by this. I suspect (1) my setter is mutating the actual 'constructor', and (2) somehow `chart1` is really a reference to this constructor, rather than being a separate instance of it like I thought.

I was thinking of using `this.margin = ...` instead of `var margin =`, but since this is the suggested pattern I wanted to post here first. What am I missing?

Comment: don't use new - the method StackedAreaChart() returns the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following Mike's tutorial, you shouldn't be using `new` when creating the chart:

```
var chart1 = StackedAreaChart();

d3.select('#chart1')
  .data([data])
  .call(chart1);
```

`StackedAreaChart` will return a function, and that function will be called once for each element in the selection when the data is binded.

Comment: Even without `new`, the problem is still there. http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/YZ6Ea/4/

Comment: You missed a semicolon in the declaration of variables for `StackedAreaChart`, that transformed the chart variables in global variables (`xScale`, `yScale`, etc). The updated fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pnavarrc/YZ6Ea/5/

Comment: You can avoid that kind of mistakes using a linter, like http://www.jshint.com. You will polish your code and learn best practices at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, what's the difference between using or not using `new`?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript